# Excel VBA Onaction with .Select or .ScrollColumn

Tags: vba, excel

Good Morning everyone,

I am facing a strange Problem in Excel VBA.

So, I have this minimal Example. The only thing it's supposed to do is, add a Button to the Rightklick context menu. This button should then select a cell.

I searched a bit on StackOverflow and found a solution to passing string arguments in `.onaction`. But then it gets tricky. I can assign a Range and I can Print the Address and the second Argument in a Mesgbox. But I can't set Breakpoints and even `stop` doesn't work, nor will `.select` or `.ScrollColumn` do anything.

To Replicate just copy the Following code into a standard Module and Execute `AddContextmenu` to add the Button to the Contextmenu.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub AddContextmenu()

    Dim MySubMenu As CommandBarControl
    Dim i As Long

    'Clear Previous Menu Items
    For Each MySubMenu In Application.CommandBars("Cell").Controls
        If Not MySubMenu.BuiltIn Then
            MySubMenu.Delete
        End If
    Next

    'add menu
  AddScrollButtons Application.CommandBars("Cell"), 1
End Sub

Public Sub AddScrollButtons(ByVal ContextMenu As CommandBar, ByVal baseindex As Long)
    Dim cbb As CommandBarButton
    Dim sFunction As String

    'Add Button
    Set cbb = ContextMenu.Controls.Add(Temporary:=True)
    With cbb

        sFunction = BuildProcArgString("ScrolltoColTest", "$F$10", "TestArg") ' Get Onaction string
        .OnAction = sFunction
        .Caption = "Scroll Tester"
        .Style = msoButtonAutomatic
    End With
End Sub

Function BuildProcArgString(ByVal ProcName As String, ParamArray Args() As Variant)
    Dim tempArg As Variant
    Dim temp As String

    For Each tempArg In Args
    temp = temp + Chr(34) + tempArg + Chr(34) + ","
    Next
    BuildProcArgString = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!" & ProcName + "(" + Left(temp, Len(temp) - 1) + ")" ' (Workbook has to be included to ensure that the sub will be executed in the correct workbook)
End Function

Public Sub ScrolltoColTest(Addr As String, OtherArg As String)
    Dim cell As Range
    Set cell = ActiveSheet.Range(Addr) 'Get Cell that sould be selected from Addr

    MsgBox cell.Address & vbNewLine & OtherArg 'Test if the Arguments have been passed correctly and the cell has been assigned
    Stop 'Why doesn' this stop?
    cell.Select 'Why doesn't this do anything
   ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = cell.Column 'Why doesn't this do anything
End Sub
```

As you will see in `ScrolltoColTest` the Part after the Msgbox will not work at all. 
Does anyone know why that happens?